# How to send a table names as parameters to a function which performs a join on them?

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, join

Currently I used the following code for joining tables.

```
Booking.joins(:table1, :table2, :table3, :table4).other_queries
```

However, the number of tables to be joined with depends on certain conditions. The other_queries also form a very large chain. So, I am duplicating a lot of code just because I need to perform joins differently.

So, I want to implement something like this

```
def method(params)
    Booking.joins(params).other_queries
end
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just `Booking.joins(*params).other_queries` is what you need?

Operator `*` transforms array into list of params, for example:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
any_method(*arr) # is equal to any_method(1,2,3)
```

However, if `params` is smth came from user I recommend you not to trust it, it probably could be security issue. But if you trust it or filter it - why not.

Answer (score 1):

```
SAFE_JOINS = [:table1, :table2, :table3]

def method(params)
  booking = Booking.scoped # or Booking.all if you are rails 5
  (params[:joins] & SAFE_JOINS.map(&:to_s)).each do |j|
    booking = booking.joins(j.intern)
  end
end
```